# 1 sample t-test from summarized data in R

Tags: r, t-test

I can perform a 1 sample t-test in R with the t.test command. This requires actual sets of data. I can't use summary statistics (sample size, sample mean, standard deviation). I can work around this utilizing the BSDA package. But are there any other ways to accomplish this 1-sample-T in R without the BSDA pacakage?

Comment: Yeah. You could just do it 'by hand' using statistical theory.

Comment: Use something like this `2*pt(-(abs(mean-mu))*sqrt(n)/sd, df=n-1)` where `mean`, `mu`, `n` and `sd` are the sample mean, null hypothesis, sample size, and sample standard deviation, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways. I'll list a few:

- directly calculate the p-value by computing the statistic and calling `pt` with that and the df as arguments, as commenters suggest above (it can be done with a single short line in R - ekstroem shows the two-tailed test case; for the one tailed case you wouldn't double it)
- alternatively, if it's something you need a lot, you could convert that into a nice robust function, even adding in tests against non-zero mu and confidence intervals if you like. Presumably if you go this route you'' want to take advantage of the functionality built around the `htest` class

  (code and even a reasonably complete function can be found in the answers to this [stats.SE question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30394/how-to-perform-two-sample-t-tests-in-r-by-inputting-sample-statistics-rather-tha).)
- If samples are not huge (smaller than a few million, say), you can simulate data with the exact same mean and standard deviation and call the ordinary t.test function. If `m` and `s` and `n` are the mean, sd and sample size, `t.test(scale(rnorm(n))*s+m)` should do (it doesn't matter what distribution you use, so `runif` would suffice). Note the importance of calling `scale` there. This makes it easy to change your alternative or get a CI without writing more code, but it wouldn't be suitable if you had millions of observations and needed to do it more than a couple of times.
- call a function in a different package that will calculate it -- there's at least one or two other such packages (you don't make it clear whether using BSDA was a problem or whether you wanted to avoid packages altogether)